# process.env variable is undefined in .js file and not in .ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables

In my Typescript project I have some .js files.
I could get env variables from process.env just fine in .ts file, but not in .js file.
in .js file they are all `undefined`.

***EDIT***
I just `console.log()` them, and they are `undefined`.

Here is my `utils/config.ts` file

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const path = `${__dirname}/../.env`;

dotenv.config({ path })
```

How to resolve this situation? Please don't ask to make js file a ts file :)

Comment: how do you know they are undefined? can we see some code? do you get an error?

Comment: have you configured dotenv where you are using it?

Comment: also dotenv returns error if there is any, `console.log(dotenv.config({ path }).error)` might yeald something

Comment: thank you all for the idea, I'll write the answer soon :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments I thought I need to configure `dotenv` for js files as well.
So, I have added

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `${__dirname}/../../.env` });
```

in .js file, and it worked.

Thanks for the help.